# Evenly distribute amount with limitations

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for a way to evenly distribute an amount x among a set of n nodes. This can be achieved by giving each node x/n. However to complicate things, some nodes have limits (different limits).

I have written a simple and stupid way of solving this this, but I'm curious if there exists something more efficient.

```py
remaining = x
remaining_nodes = len(nodes)

while remaining > 0 and remaining_nodes > 0:
    increase_amount = remaining / remaining_nodes
    for node in nodes:
        increase_amount_node = min(increase_amount, node.max_value - node.value)
        node.value += increase_amount_node
        remaining -= increase_amount_node
        if node.value == node.max_value:
            remaining_nodes -= 1
```

Can this be done in a better way? Is this a well-researched problem and I'm just failing at looking in the right places?

Thankful for any answers!

Comment: What is the objective you want to minimize? Do you want to minimize the variance or something else? From looking at it I think your proposed algorithm does minimize the variance. But I think the runtime could be improved to O(nlog(n)) by first ordering the nodes by `max_value`.

Comment: Yes, minimized variance is what I'm going for. Thank you, ordering should improve efficiency. However, where I'm implementing this the order can not be altered, and copying the structure and sorting the copy is expensive in this case.

Comment: Can you access a specific element in constant time (like `nodes[i]`)? Then you could simply store a sorted list of indices.

Comment: Yes, I will do something along those lines. All memory is statically allocated which is the main source of difficulty in implementing your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a O(nlog(n)) version of the algorithm you proposed which is O(n^2).

```
ordered_nodes = order_nodes_by_max_value_increasing(nodes)
remaining = x
for i, node in enumerate(ordered_nodes):
   node.value = min(remaining/(n-i), node.max_value)
   remaining -= node.value
```

Note that when `remaining > 0` at the end all maximal values are hit. The runtime O(nlog(n)) comes from the sorting. And the result is the same as the one from your algorithm, which is optimal with respect to the variance.

I use `enumerate` like the `python` version of it. It enumerates through the objects starting at `0`.

Comment: Very elegant. Where I'm implementing this the order can not be altered, and copying the structure and sorting the copy is expensive in this case. But this is enough insight for me to improve my solution. Thank you!